# Reload collection

Tags: magento2, collection

Is there any chance to **reload collection in Magento 2**?

For example:

```
foreach($items as $singleItems){
    $collection = $this->_myCollection->addFieldToFilter('filed', $singleItems->something);
...
}
```

For each iteration i need **clear collection and load one more time**.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To clear a collection you can call:

```
$this->_myCollection->clear();
```

To reload a collection you can call:

```
$this->_myCollection->load();
```

Comment: Note that `load` without a previous `clear` does nothing if the collection was already loaded.

Comment: @fschmengler totally you usually see both lines one after the other when a reload is needed

Comment: Perhaps you should add a full example to the answer: `foreach($items as $singleItems){
            $collection = $this->_myCollection
                ->clear()
                ->addFieldToFilter('filed', $singleItems->something)
                ->load();
        }`

Answer (score 11):

If you applied filters, you can reset collection with :

```
$this->_myCollection->clear()->getSelect()->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::WHERE);
```

Then :

```
$this->_myCollection->addFieldToFilter('field', $singleItems->getSomething());
$this->_myCollection->load();
```

Comment: This is worked like charm. upvoted (Y) Thanks :)

Comment: This is the best answer, it worked nice!

Answer (score 0):

you can use CollectionFactory instance Collection.
the factory class by creating method every time create a fresh object without recent data

Comment: yes but you don't want to keep creating objects especially in a loop, unless there is a case where the class is reusing the existing object behind the scenes.